# why are the overarrows too short and the sqrt missing its vinculum?

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math

[image: the not-quite-right results]

I've been fighting with XeLaTeX (from a full TeX Live 2011 install on a linux box) for the past few hours and am finally almost at the result I want, but (as shown above) the overarrows aren't stretching to cover all the letters and the sqrt doesn't have its vinculum/overbar and I'm at a loss.  What can I do to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={350pt,45pt},margin=0pt}

% no page numbers (and maybe other cleanness?)
\pagestyle{empty}

% don't hyphenate, don't indent
\hyphenpenalty=100000
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}


% color
\usepackage{color}
\pagecolor{black}

% XeTeX fonts
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{sfmath}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Bera Sans}
\setmathfont{STIXGeneral}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{Bera Sans}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Bera Sans Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{Bera Sans Bold Oblique}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{Bera Sans Oblique}

\begin{document}\fontsize{9}{13}\selectfont\color{white}
This means that $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$ contains $F$  We write that as $3=\sqrt{9}$.  The \emph{square root} symbol is sometimes called a \emph{radical} symbol.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\setmathfont{XITS Math}`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks.  Changing the `STIXGeneral` to `XITS Math` fixed the radical and moved the overarrow to the center, but didn't stretch it—see http://i.stack.imgur.com/DqJZc.png

Comment: I don't think that `\overleftrightarrow` is stretchable.

Comment: @egreg: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php renders it as if it's stretchable... I thought I'd seen it stretchable elsewhere, but maybe not.  Is there something I should use instead for the same effect?

Comment: It is with pdflatex; it doesn't seem to be so with unicode-math.

Comment: It does stretch by default with the original amsmath definition

Comment: I know your pain. When I first got XeTeX, I have tested various new math fonts - XITS, Cambria, Asana. They all had some problems (fat ugly sum symbols, too tight \ldots, misaligned `\not=`, bad kerning, too small parentheses in binomials, roots too far away, the mentioned arrows over text completely wrong). I was so disappointed, that I came back to using original math fonts. I would stick with the default math font but I use the almost as good `mathpazo` package, because it plays much better with Minion Pro as main roman font.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arrow stretches for me if I add

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\savedoverleftrightarrow\overleftrightarrow
```

then use `\savedoverleftrightarrow` in the expression.

Comment: Yes, because it uses the amsmath definition. Something that the developers of unicode-math should look at.

Comment: This did it—I put `\let\savedoverleftrightarrow\overleftrightarrow` right after loading `amsmath`, then `\def\overleftrightarrow{\savedoverleftrightarrow}` after all the other package loads and now `\overleftrightarrow` works as expected.

Comment: @egreg: Since I'm loading `unicode-math` before `amsmath`, wouldn't the `amsmath` definition overwrite one coming from `unicode-math`?  If so, wouldn't the problem be in `xltxtra` or `sfmath`?

Comment: @Isaac a whole load of definitions appear to be delayed (you set up the math fonts later for example) but I didn't trace exactly where the erroneous definition is coming from (actually that was the first time I've run xelatex:-)

Comment: @Isaac `amsmath` should be loaded before `unicode-math` and `sfmath` doesn't make much sense in this context.

Comment: @egreg: I took out `sfmath` (which was probably a holdover from earlier attempts at sans-serif math) and swap the order of `amsmath` and `unicode-math` and everything seems to be working well (thanks!).  Is there a reference for the order in which I should be loading packages, or some rule of thumb as to how to order things?

Comment: @Isaac Unfortunately there are not many rules. In this case the advice is in the documentation of `unicode-math`.